# Difference between double ** and double (*)[2] in C

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gcc-warning

What is the difference between a double ** and a double (*)[2].

If I understand well, a double ** is a pointer to a pointer of double, so it could be a  2D array of any size whereas double (*)[2] is a pointer to an array of double[2].

So if it is right, how can it be passed successfully to a function.

For instance in :

```
void pcmTocomplex(short *data, double *outm[2])
```

if I pass a double (*)[2] as a parameter, I have the following warning :

```
warning: passing argument 2 of ‘pcmTocomplex’ from incompatible pointer type
note: expected ‘double **’ but argument is of type ‘double (*)[2]’
```

What is the right way to pass a double (*)[2] to a function ?

EDIT : calling code

```
fftw_complex        *in;             /* typedef on double[2] */
in = (fftw_complex *) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * 1024);

pcmTocomplex(data, in);
```

Comment: show us the calling code

Comment: `double *[2]` is not the same as `double (*)[2]`.

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void pcmTocomplex(short *data, double *outm[2])
```

This second parameter , you seen in this function prototype imply array of double pointers and not actually what  you want.

```
void pcmTocomplex(short *data, double (*outm)[2])
```

This how it should look like if you want , what you expect.

Answer (score 3):

`double *outm[2]` is not the same as `double (*outm)[2]`.  The first is an array of pointers (and is equivalent to `double **` in this context); the second is a pointer to an array.

If in doubt, use [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to change second parameter type to this:

```
void pcmTocomplex(short *data, double (*outm)[2])
```

Note the second parameter is changed to `double (*outm)[2]`.

Also note that in your code, `double *outm[2]` in the parameter is *exactly* same as `double **outm`.